# Why is my `Stream` being closed at runtime?

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, consumer

I have this bit of code:

```
var blong = Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ZERO, bi -> bi.add(BigInteger.ONE))
    .collect(Collector.of(
        () -> Stream.of(),
        (s, bi) -> Stream.concat(s, Stream.of(bi)),
        (s1, s2) -> Stream.concat(s1, s2),
        s -> s
    ));

System.out.println(blong.getClass().getName());
```

It doesn't work properly. I'm getting an `IllegalStateException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.spliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:346)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Stream.concat(Stream.java:1618)
at UninitializedTest.lambda$2(UninitializedTest.java:28)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Stream$1.tryAdvance(Stream.java:1469)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:332)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
at UninitializedTest.main(UninitializedTest.java:27)
```

It appears that the `Stream`s being returned by my `Supplier` are being closed immediately upon creation.

Even if I create a `Stream` from an empty `List` or a `Stream` with some actual `BigInteger` data in it, I get the same error.

**Why is my stream being closed?**

Comment: Can you clarify what output you expect? Why are you trying to collect into a Stream compared to using flatmap, for example?

Comment: @OneCricketeer The ultimate objective was to be able to pass an arbitrary `Stream` in and have it come out the other end.  Then I can do other things that accept `Collector`s, like `teeing()`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, let's dissect the *custom collector* you've created:

```
Collector.of(
    () -> Stream.of(),                          // Container - this object is meant accumulate the result by consuming stream elements (in this case it can't really change its state, but nominally its still a container)
    (s, bi) -> Stream.concat(s, Stream.of(bi)), // Accumulator - is meant to define how stream elements should be accumulated in the container (again in this case we can't do anything with the container)
    (s1, s2) -> Stream.concat(s1, s2),          // Combiner - defines how containers should be merged while executing stream in parallel (NB: - we can replace it with a method reference Stream::concat)
    s -> s                                      // Finisher function - describes the final transformation which should be performed with container (NB: since it doesn't perform any action we can omit this argument, there's an overloaded version which doesn't expect Finisher)
)
```

First of all it's worth to point out that *Stream* is **not** a *container of data* (like a Collection).

Hence, providing an empty stream `() -> Stream.of()` as a *container* of the *collector* is a mistake - the *container* needs to be mutable. But we **can't** push elements into an empty stream.

Secondly, the *accumulator* (the second argument of `Collector.of()`) of your *custom collector* is **not** doing what you probably expect it to do.

*Accumulator* is a `BiConsumer<R, T>` and you've implemented it as follows:

```
(s, bi) -> Stream.concat(s, Stream.of(bi))
```

Here `Stream.concat()` consumes all the elements from the stream `s` and a stream returned by `Stream.of(bi)` and generates a new unnamed stream, which very soon becomes a prey of the Garbage Collector. Reminder: `BiConsumer` doesn't return a value, so the stream returned by `concat()` vanishes.

The stream `s` remains (meaning the *collector* knows it's reference), but it's already consumed while executing `concat()`, i.e. it's **closed**. It happens at the point when the first stream element (`BigInteger.ZERO`) gets processes. And when the *collector* tries to process the second element, you're getting an exception because `concat()` attempts to consume the stream `s` which has been already closed.

---

> When the `Consumer` fires, I'm expecting the `Stream<Stream<BigInteger>>` to be consumed, returning a `Stream<BigInteger>`

Firstly, `BiConsumer` as well as `Consumer` has an `abstract` method [`accept()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html#accept(T,U)) which is `void`, it isn't meant to return anything.

> It appears that the Streams being returned by my `Supplier` are being closed

Secondly, it feels like you have a misconception of how Collector work. An instance of a *mutable container* would be created **only once** in the sequential scenario of execution (and one container per thread in parallel, unless you specify that it's a *concurrent collector* by providing `Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT`, in such case all thread would share the same container).

*Container* should be a mutable object (otherwise it would not be useful like in your case), and its job is to accumulate stream elements. I.e. *container* changes its state, while *collector* consumes elements from the stream.

The stream returned by [`Stream.iterate(seed,f)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate(T,java.util.function.UnaryOperator)) would be of type `Stream<BigInteger>`.

The *Container* produced by *supplier* `() -> Stream.of()` would be of type `Stream<Object>` because the compiler can't infer the type of empty stream, unless you explicitly specify it using Type-Witness like `.<BigInteger>of()`.

For that reason, the stream returned by `concat()` in side the *accumulator* would be also of type `Stream<Object>`. And reminder this stream would be ignored.

There wouldn't be such a beast like `Stream<Stream<BigInteger>>` anywhere, either in the pipeline, or inside the collector.

And lastly, I'll reiterate that it's inherently **impossible** to add an element into a `Stream`.

Comment: I'm aware that it's an infinite `Stream`.

Comment: Getting an `OutOfMemoryError` would have been much more enlightening then what I **am** getting.

Comment: @TrippKinetics The point it that the second argument of the `Collector.of()` doesn't return you a stream, because it's a consumer. Conversely, it consumes the stream.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Mention of infinite stream is just a remark. If you consider it destructive, I can remove it.

Comment: Except, the `Stream` as it exists at that point in the pipeline is not a `Stream<BigInteger>`  It's a `Stream<Stream<BigInteger>>`.

Comment: When the `Consumer` fires, I'm expecting the `Stream<Stream<BigInteger>>` to be consumed, returning a `Stream<BigInteger>`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Consumer returns nothing!

Comment: It's not meant to return anything.  When you're doing (for example) `toList()`, the `Consumer` simply adds the element to the `List`.  I'm just creating a `Stream` containing only the new element and appending it to the end of my working `Stream`.

Comment: I should've said the `Stream<Stream<BigInteger>>` is consumed, and it ***results*** in the next `Stream<BigInteger>` being tacked onto the end of the working `Stream<BigInteger>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247459/discussion-between-tripp-kinetics-and-alexander-ivanchenko).